# How do I make Christmas last all year?

Tags: terraria

With the holiday season coming to an end, the time left to enjoy our presents, the Frost Legion, and Santa Claus is short. As a fairly casual player who hasn't yet made it to hardmode, I'm worried I won't be able to unlock everything before I miss the opportunity.

Is there a way to keep "holiday mode" active? As an alternative, is there a way to access Santa or the Frost Legion without holiday mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless someone makes a mod or you continually reset your system clock, it's not possible. As soon as you enter a world outside of the designated holiday time frame (Dec. 15th-31st), Santa will die instantly.

You can keep your access to Santa Claus by making a dedicated "Santa world" with him in it, and only entering it on special occasions when you need him (of course tampering with your system clock beforehand).

You *can* start the Frost Legion event outside of the holidays, but they will not drop presents, so your supply of Snow Globes will eventually run out. If your world is not in hardmode yet, keep your presents and unpack them when it is; else you will get no Snow Globes at all and the event will be unavailable.

Comment: Any idea how well clock changing works with dedicated servers? If the clients' clocks don't need set back as well, maybe I'll just make a Santa Server. ^.^

Comment: @BenBlank I'm not *entirely* sure, but that should work, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Change the clock time on your device. That should work!